# How to query multiple servers via Registered Servers / Server Groups?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We use a certain HealthCare info system that breaks our hospitals into multiple servers and my company is growing and this is causing a simple query to need to be run in 5+ server databases.

I recently learned about setting up Registered Server Local Groups and set them up. Then hit a wall when trying to query.

The problem is our databases are prefixed based on the environment, so I need a way to run the one query with two different db table names.

Example:

> select * from **live**fdb.dbo.BlahBlah
>
> select * from **test**fdb.dbo.BlahBlah

Was hoping there is some way when I query to use a wildcard for those first 4 characters.

Comment: Nope... they have to be specified. If you want to automate it you'll need to look into dynamic SQL. But for a small number of servers better to hardcode them.

Comment: Why not set up two registered server groups, one with the live servers and one with the test servers? Do you really want to be blending live & test data in your query results anyway?

Comment: Take a look into [Central Management Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/administer-multiple-servers-using-central-management-servers) which can let you query multiple servers at once (and there will be an additional column with the server name).

Comment: if you are OK to run another script (may be calling a stored procedure)  before running this query?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but you'll have to use linked servers instead. Multi-server queries in SSMS won't work for you in this situation.

Given your constraints, I'd do this:

1. On one server, create a linked server to the other servers.
2. Create a view that queries each of the servers and uses UNION ALL to combine the results.
3. Just query that view from one server.